# php curl cannot get tls version that currently use

Tags: php, curl, openssl, tls1.2, php-curl

I am trying to get the version of tls which is currently used when invoking the url.
I'm trying to get the tls version from php curl like the command curl in Ubuntu.

for example:

```
curl -v https://qpyl.uas-gw.info
* Rebuilt URL to: https://qpyl.uas-gw.info/
*   Trying 54.199.158.6...
* Connected to qpyl.uas-gw.info (54.199.158.6) port 443 (#0)
* found 1 certificates in ca.crt
* found 692 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

like this to show the tls version result.

But I cannot get the version in php curl like the above curl does

> SSL connection using **TLS1.2** / ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384

***php openssl version:*** **openssl/1.0.2g**

***php version:*** **5.5.38**.

Comment: have a look at this, might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27904854/verify-if-curl-is-using-tls

Comment: I already tried with this but cannot get the tls version. please , do you have another. Thanks

Comment: well it does gives me this  " TLS 1.2 " when i follow the above example.

Comment: Can it echo out the version result without reading the documents the link that indicated?

Comment: No, it doesn't. you need to send curl request to that url and read the response , screenshot => https://www.screencast.com/t/BCvvZc9Inq0

Comment: please be here bro, I don't understand that url https://www.howsmyssl.com/a/check. 
because I get the result I think it is written by default.

Comment: ok, you said above  " I am trying to get the version of tls which is currently used when invoking the url " .  Now you can use " https://www.howsmyssl.com/ " to check what SSL client you using.

Comment: I just can check only with this url right?

Comment: yes . this will tell you TLS version

Comment: Thanks @ RashFlash.

Comment: @HarrisDingtai, it sounds like you have the same problem as me. You want to be able to test various urls to see if THEY support TLS.... not check if your request is using TLS version X. I made a new question for that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49186863/php-how-to-see-if-a-server-supports-tls-1-0

Comment: Thanks you @coderama