# I am using the Consolibyte PHP Quickbooks connect. I am getting an error after connecting to quickbooks, something went wrong fetching user token

Tags: php, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online, qbwc

I am using the Consolibyte PHP Quickbooks connect.  I am getting an error after connecting to quickbooks:

> something went wrong fetching user token

If I try again I get the error:

> ErrorException in IntuitAnywhere.php line 468: Undefined index:
>   oauth_token

I've been using this for almost a year now with no issues.  Yesterday we weren't able to receive payment data from the api.  I tried disconnecting and reconnecting and this started happening.  I'm not sure what to do.  We have mcrypt setup and we are using php 7.  I also updated to the newest version of the github repo to see if that would fix it but it's still doing the same thing.

Thank you for your help!

Here is my config file

```
          error_reporting(E_ALL);
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);


// Your application token (Intuit will give you this when you register an Intuit Anywhere app)
        $token = env('TOKEN');

// Your OAuth consumer key and secret (Intuit will give you both of these when you register an Intuit app)
//
// IMPORTANT:
//  To pass your tech review with Intuit, you'll have to AES encrypt these and
//  store them somewhere safe.
//
// The OAuth request/access tokens will be encrypted and stored for you by the
//  PHP DevKit IntuitAnywhere classes automatically.
        $oauth_consumer_key = env('KEY');
        $oauth_consumer_secret = env('SECRET');

// If you're using DEVELOPMENT TOKENS, you MUST USE SANDBOX MODE!!!  If you're in PRODUCTION, then DO NOT use sandbox.
        $sandbox = env('SANDBOX');     // When you're using development tokens
      //  $sandbox = true;    // When you're using production tokens

// This is the URL of your OAuth auth handler page
        $quickbooks_oauth_url = env('OAUTH');

// This is the URL to forward the user to after they have connected to IPP/IDS via OAuth
        $quickbooks_success_url = env('SUCCESS');

// This is the menu URL script
        $quickbooks_menu_url = env('MENU');

// This is a database connection string that will be used to store the OAuth credentials
// $dsn = 'pgsql://username:password@hostname/database';
// $dsn = 'mysql://username:password@hostname/database';
        $dsn = 'mysqli://'.env('DB_USER').':'.env('DB_PASS').'@'. env('DB_HOST').'/'.env('DB');

// You should set this to an encryption key specific to your app
        $encryption_key = env('ENCRYPT');

// Do not change this unless you really know what you're doing!!!  99% of apps will not require a change to this.
        $the_username = 'DO_NOT_CHANGE_ME';

// The tenant that user is accessing within your own app
        $the_tenant = 12345;

// Initialize the database tables for storing OAuth information
        if (!\QuickBooks_Utilities::initialized($dsn)) {
        // Initialize creates the neccessary database schema for queueing up requests and logging
            \QuickBooks_Utilities::initialize($dsn);
        }

// Instantiate our Intuit Anywhere auth handler
//
// The parameters passed to the constructor are:
//  $dsn
//  $oauth_consumer_key     Intuit will give this to you when you create a new Intuit Anywhere application at AppCenter.Intuit.com
//  $oauth_consumer_secret  Intuit will give this to you too
//  $this_url               This is the full URL (e.g. http://path/to/this/file.php) of THIS SCRIPT
//  $that_url               After the user authenticates, they will be forwarded to this URL
//
        $IntuitAnywhere = new \QuickBooks_IPP_IntuitAnywhere($dsn, $encryption_key, $oauth_consumer_key, $oauth_consumer_secret, $quickbooks_oauth_url, $quickbooks_success_url);

// Are they connected to QuickBooks right now?
        if ($IntuitAnywhere->check($the_username, $the_tenant) and
            $IntuitAnywhere->test($the_username, $the_tenant)
        ) {
        // Yes, they are
            $quickbooks_is_connected = true;

            // Set up the IPP instance
            $IPP = new \QuickBooks_IPP($dsn);

            // Get our OAuth credentials from the database
            $creds = $IntuitAnywhere->load($the_username, $the_tenant);

            // Tell the framework to load some data from the OAuth store
            $IPP->authMode(
                \QuickBooks_IPP::AUTHMODE_OAUTH,
                $the_username,
                $creds
            );

            if ($sandbox) {
            // Turn on sandbox mode/URLs
                $IPP->sandbox(true);
            }

            // Print the credentials we're using
            //print_r($creds);

            // This is our current realm
            $realm = $creds['qb_realm'];

            // Load the OAuth information from the database
            $Context = $IPP->context();

            // Get some company info
            $CompanyInfoService = new \QuickBooks_IPP_Service_CompanyInfo();
            $quickbooks_CompanyInfo = $CompanyInfoService->get($Context, $realm);

            return [$realm, $Context];
        } else {
            // No, they are not
            $quickbooks_is_connected = false;

            return [$realm, $Context];
        }
    }
```

Here is my connection file.  It's a blade template so the script is included in my footer:

```
    @extends('app')

@section('content')


    <?php if ($quickbooks_is_connected): ?>
    <ipp:blueDot></ipp:blueDot>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div>
    <p>
        QuickBooks connection status:

    <?php if ($quickbooks_is_connected): ?>
    <div style="border: 2px solid green; text-align: center; padding: 8px; color: green;">
        CONNECTED!<br>
        <br>

    </div>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="disconnect">Disconnect from QuickBooks</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                (If you do this, you'll have to go back through the authorization/connection process to get connected again)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="reconnect">Reconnect / refresh connection</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                (QuickBooks connections expire after 6 months, so you have to this roughly every 5 and 1/2 months)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="diagnostics">Diagnostics about QuickBooks connection</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <?php else: ?>
    <div style="border: 2px solid red; text-align: center; padding: 8px; color: red;">
        <b>NOT</b> CONNECTED!<br>
        <br>
        <ipp:connectToIntuit></ipp:connectToIntuit>
        <br>
        <br>
        You must authenticate to QuickBooks <b>once</b> before you can exchange data with it. <br>
        <br>
        <strong>You only have to do this once!</strong> <br><br>

        After you've authenticated once, you never have to go
        through this connection process again. <br>
        Click the button above to
        authenticate and connect.
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    </p>
</div>
@endsection
@section('scripts')
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://appcenter.intuit.com/Content/IA/intuit.ipp.anywhere.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        intuit.ipp.anywhere.setup({
            menuProxy: '<?php print($quickbooks_menu_url); ?>',
            grantUrl: '<?php print($quickbooks_oauth_url); ?>'
        });
    </script>
@endsection
```

I appologize if I'm not posting correctly, I haven't asked any questions on here before.

I ran the troubleshooting scripts mentioned by Keith, here is the output:

```
> Trying to hit URL: oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_request_token Did we disable SSL checks? false * Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache * Could not resolve host: oauth.intuit.com * Closing connection 67 

Trying to hit URL: appcenter.intuit.com/api/v1/Connection/Reconnect Did we disable SSL checks? false * Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache * Could not resolve host: appcenter.intuit.com * Closing connection 68 

Trying to hit URL: oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_request_token Did we disable SSL checks? true * Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache * Could not resolve host: oauth.intuit.com * Closing connection 69 

Trying to hit URL: appcenter.intuit.com/api/v1/Connection/Reconnect Did we disable SSL checks? true * Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache * Could not resolve host: appcenter.intuit.com * Closing connection 70 

php version: 7.0.1-4+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 mcrypt extension? true mcrypt module rijndael-256? NULL curl extension? true
```

Comment: SO what did you change last, just before it started going wrong?

Comment: nothing.  I hadn't touched the code in months.  @RiggsFolly

Comment: Ok, but what else changed. Did you upgrade PHP or change anything else in the general environment

Comment: I changed domain names but nothing else should have changed.  I upgraded to php 7 about 6 months ago but I had it working after that.

Comment: Does quickbook care about the domain name? Is that something that needs to be changed in the QB config for example

Comment: I updated all the config files with the new domain name when I made the change.  It does need to know the domain name for it to connect.

Comment: Please post the output of the troubleshooting.php script: https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/partner_platform/example_app_ipp_v3/troubleshooting.php

Comment: @KeithPalmerJr. I updated the question with the output.  I had to remove the http:// parts because stackoverflow was considering them links and I don't have enough rep points yet to post that many links.

Comment: Your PHP installation/CURL module doesn't work with HTTPS:// links it looks like. Fix your PHP installation so that you can use CURL to fetch HTTPS links.

Comment: :)  Thank you so much @KeithPalmerJr. I followed the answer in the link below and was able to get it working again!  I owe you a gift. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9774349/php-curl-not-working-with-https