# PHP cURL issues only on some requests

Tags: php, curl, error-handling, timeout

Good day..

I have a web app that makes requests to another server through proxies. Now i would say 99% of these requests works completely fine hand i have no issue what so ever and receive the response back.

However some requests ( again a very few amount ) will return HTTP response code 0, which means curl failed. After debug with curl_error i have collected these 2 errors.

1. OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to URL.
2. Operation timed out after 7000 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received

Now the second one is self explanatory. Surely the SSL error is just due to a dodgy proxy otherwise i would get this response with every request and not just 1% ( to the same urls ) ? im pretty sure my curl config is ok. ( below ).

```
curl_setopt_array($this->ch, array(
                        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
                        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
                        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => 1,
                        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
                        CURLOPT_POST => 0,
                        CURLOPT_ENCODING => 'gzip',
                        CURLOPT_HEADER => 0
                ));
```

Should i just add a curl exec retry if response is nothing / code = 0 ?

Thank you.

Comment: See if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9774349/php-curl-not-working-with-https helps wil SSL

Comment: Yes thank you that helps i think CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER will work just fine. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

yeah, just retry once or twice, and know that you're not alone, i wrote this some time back:

```
echo 'file: ' . $file . ' url: ' . $raw_url . '..' . PHP_EOL;
try {
    $headers = implode ( " ", $hc->exec ( $url )->getResponseHeaders () );
} catch ( Exception $ex ) {
    try {
        $headers = implode ( " ", $hc->exec ( $url )->getResponseHeaders () );
    } catch ( Exception $ex ) {
        // sometimes connection fails for no good reason, and a retry (or 2) fixes it...
        // here we give up and deliberately not catch the 3rd exception (if any)
        $headers = implode ( " ", $hc->exec ( $url )->getResponseHeaders () );
    }
}
```