# Call to undefined function curl_init()

Tags: php, foursquare

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [curl_init() function not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477535/curl-init-function-not-working)

I am using PHP for accessing the Foursquare API. I have set up everything for the authentication with Foursquare. But as soon as I click on the "Allow" button, my callback.php gives me the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in C:\wamp\www\EpiFoursquare.php on line 119

Call Stack

Time    Memory  Function                          Location
0.0007  372592  {main}( )                         ..\callback.php:0
0.0039  571896  EpiFoursquare->getAccessToken( )  ..\callback.php:17
0.0040  572928  EpiFoursquare->request( )         ..\EpiFoursquare.php:31
```

Where does this error come from? I cannot find the origin. Please help me out.

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with foursquare at all. Turn on `curl` module in php. "I just dont know, why it is originating." --- why don't you read error message then?!

Comment: sir actually I am getting this error, it say  "Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in C:\wamp\www\EpiFoursquare.php on line 119" and all the necessary files are placed in the folder, like callback.php, index.php, EpiCurl.php

Comment: `curl` is a php extension http://nz.php.net/manual/en/curl.installation.php

Comment: I am connected to 4square web site, on callback, it must f=give me the access token. but when I echo $token["access_token"], it is empty.

Comment: any one please help me out. error is actually "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'EpiFoursquareBadRequestException' with message '{"error":"redirect_uri_mismatch"}' in /home/apmtpuci/public_html/4square/EpiFoursquare.php:244 Stack trace: #0 /home/apmtpuci/public_html/4square/EpiFoursquare.php(208): EpiFoursquareException::raise(Object(EpiCurlManager), false) #1"

Answer (score 12):

You need to initialize the cURL extension: http://php.net/manual/en/curl.installation.php

Comment: I did this by enabling the php_curl.dll extension in the php.ini file (as FlatLander also mentions). Since I use WAMP Server, I did not need to do anything else, as the ssleay32.dll, libeay32.dll, and php_curl.dll files are already in the right places inside my C:\wamp\ directory.

Answer (score 9):

1. remove `;` from `extension=php_curl.dll` in `php.ini` ;
2. ensure that `ssleay32.dll` and `libeay32.dll` are in `Windows/system32` ;
3. copy `php_curl.dll` into `Windows\System32` as well.

This worked for me!

Comment: I tried this but it did not work for me. I am not sure if thing have been updated in the last few years. I am using PHP 5.6.13.  

As above I had to remove `;` from `extension=php_curl.dll` in `php.ini`, I also had to remove `;` from `extension_dir = "ext"` in `php.ini`.