# How to execute php script from the command line?

Tags: php

I have a php script by the following address `C:\Denwer\home\localhost\www\upload_record_test.php`. 
This script shows some text. But if I try to execute this script from the commmand line by command `php C:\Denwer\home\localhost\www\upload_record_test`, I get the html response with many errors and the message `Call to undefined function curl_init()`. The code:

```
<?php
    $_POST_DATA=array();
    $_POST_DATA['id']='AccountPagesView.a_book/45';
    $_POST_DATA['old_value']='1';
    $_POST_DATA['value']='2';
    $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/index.php/welcome/update_record');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST_DATA);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    $real_result=curl_exec($ch);
    $expected_result=array('result'=>'LOGIN', 'old_value'=>'1');
    $real_result=json_decode($real_result, true);
    if (count(array_intersect($real_result, $expected_result))==2)
    {
        echo "THE TEST HAS BEEN COMPLETED";
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "THE TEST HASN'T BEEN COMPLETED<br/>";
        echo "RESULT:";
        print_r($real_result);
        echo "<br/>EXPECTED RESULT:";
        print_r($expected_result);
    }
?>
```

Please, tell me, how can I execute this script from the command line and get only resulted text? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you able the run the script from browser?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call to undefined function curl_init().?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382539/call-to-undefined-function-curl-init) and [curl init function not working ?](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/4477535/curl-init-function-not-working).

Answer (score 0):

Check if curl is properly installed. If no check [this](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.setup.php) instruction from php.net.

If Yes, then your curl module may not be enabled. You have to enable the curl module, to use curl methods. You can do this by editing `php.ini` and enabling the module.

On windows:

- Open your `php.ini` file
- Find a line with `;extension=php_curl.dll`
- Remove the `;` infront and save the file
- Restart apache server

It should work.

#### **Update:**

Sometimes `safe_mode` might be causing this problem. Go to ini file and disable the `safe_mode`

```
[php.ini]
safe_mode = Off
```

Comment: Sorry, but this script works from my browser, and the cause of the error ins't a disabled curl extension.

Comment: Command line PHP uses a different php.ini, so there is a good chance that curl is disabled there.

Comment: As @JevgenijEvll said - try typing `php --ini` from your command line to see where your command line .ini file is.

Comment: @user1477886, CLI should use a different php.ini file, try to find a `cli` folder.

Comment: @user1477886, Another way you can execute the file, is by giving the script name like `php "curlfile.php"`, if the ini's are same. This should work as expected.

Comment: @user1477886, May be safe_mode is causing this. See the update

Comment: @user1477886, I am voting this question to catch some attention, then.

Comment: @user1477886, And once try to dry run the command in CLI form. Let's Say `php -r "curl_init();"`

Comment: I have got the error "Unable to load dynamic_library php_curl.dll"

Comment: One last thing from me. copy the php_curl.dll from the `ext` folder to the folder where `php_win.exe` is present. And try

Comment: Sorry, but it hasn't halped me. It doesn't work. I have just seen at results of "phpinfo()" function andd curl is enabled.