# Paypal : trouble with ipn response

Tags: php, paypal

I am uable to get the VERIFIED answer from paypal using the IPN
I'm receiving the POST data from PayPal via the notify_url. I then send it back to PayPal with cmd=_notify-validate infront of the data.

Using PayPals documented code, I'm using this to send the message to PayPal

```
$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n"; // HTTP POST request
$header.= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header.= "Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com\r\n";
$header.= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n";
$header.= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
```

Then I use this

```
if (!$fp) {
    // HTTP ERROR; 
} else {
    var_dump(fputs($fp, $header . $req));
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $res = stream_get_contents($fp, 1024); 
        if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
            //Transaction verified
        }
    }
}
```

In fact I have two $res (due to the while loop). The first does not seems to be of interest and the second is

```
55 GMT
Connection: close
Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=name%3DSANDBOX3.WEB.1%26silo_version%3D880%26app%3Dslingshot%26TIME%3D1273590100; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: X-PP-SILOVER=; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
Set-Cookie: Apache=10.72.128.11.1416751435364358; path=/; expires=Tue, 15-Nov-44 14:03:55 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=14400
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

8
VERIFIED
0
```

It seems that the first part is a header and the second part (8 VERIFIED 0) is the real response but why do I have this 0 and 8 ? Usually people use

```
 if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
```

To check that the $res is VERIFIED... So can I consider that the response is 'VERIFIED', using something like

```
if(strstr($res,'VERIFIED')) {
```

Some help please ?!?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue, and was able to solve it the same way.  If I use the sample code from PayPal I get no response at all.

But I have come across something that works using cURL here: 
https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/paypal_ipn.php.

I needed to install cURL using these instructions: 
[curl_init() function not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477535/curl-init-function-not-working)

And also download and use the cacert.pem found in the script comments.

I am still not certain why stream_get_contents() is returning the headers.  If you have figured it out, can you update this?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue than you. And I use strstr($res,'VERIFIED') to check if notification is verified.