# php.ini file nowhere to be found?

Tags: php, apache, magento

I am aware that there are a lot of questions regarding this already, but I've looked through each of them and have found nothing.

I am running php 7.0.6, and Apache2.4.  I downloaded PHP from windows.php.net/download (I got the second one down, the x86 threadsafe one). After download I extracted it straight to the `C:\` drive under `C:\php`.

I am trying to install the Magento e-commerce platform but am required to install a few PHP extensions before I can proceed (namely curl, xsl, intl, mbstring, openssl and gd)

I had a read around and found that to enable them I have to remove the semicolon before them in the `php.ini` file, so I have navigated to `C:\php` and looked for it, but can only find `php.ini-development` and `php.ini-production`, which having looked at another thread, neither is what I want.

I also read that it is sometimes just a file called php, but cannot find that either in the `C:\php` folder

I then performed a `phpinfo();` command in a php file and ran it, getting this result:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path        C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File                (none)
Scan this dir for additional .ini files  (none)
Additional .ini files parsed             (none)
```

I have then looked in the `C:\Windows` folder to no avail, and I don't know how I am supposed to find the `php.ini` file so I can remove the semicolon and load the php extensions.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: PHP "thinks" it should be in `C:\Windows` but _Loaded Configuration File   (none)_ means it isn't there and none was loaded.  Where did you get PHP and where did you put it?

Comment: i was following a thenewboston tutorial (total noob here, as probably evident), and downloaded it from http://windows.php.net/download/ (i got the second one down, the x86 threadsafe one). After download I extracted it straight to the C:\ drive under C:\php

Comment: Try in C:\Program Files (x86) or C:\Program

Comment: By 'to get mine working' I mean to get PHP to actually use the extensions after they were uncommented, I had to change the ini setting from `extension_dir = "ext"` to `extension_dir = "C:\php\ext"`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Where PHP is installed `C:\php` there is a `php.ini-development` and `php.ini-production`. You can copy or rename one of these to `php.ini`.  These are templates and have all of the default settings that are needed.  The main difference is that the development one will have error reporting turned on and the production one will not:

It should be loaded from either the PHP directory `C:\php` or `C:\windows`.  I use the PHP directory as PHP I believe, will always look in the directory from which PHP is run:

```
copy c:\php\php.ini-development c:\php\php.ini
```

Or:

```
copy c:\php\php.ini-development c:\windows\php.ini
```

My system:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path       C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File               C:\app\php\php.ini
```

Comment: I would include `copy c:\php\php.ini-development c:\windows\php.ini`.

Comment: Does it matter which one, and does it matter if I copy it or rename it?

Comment: @RobWilliams:  You should know if your system is to be used for development or production, but I can easily guess it's for development.

Comment: Edited to clarify.

Comment: @JuliePelletier Okay so I'll copy the development one and rename it php.ini? And should that be in c:\windows or c:\php?

Comment: Based on your `phpinfo()`, put it in c:\windows

Comment: @RobWilliams After you get the file copied, the next problems you'll probably run into: 1) You'll need to restart your web server after setting up the new php.ini before you'll see anything different 2) If your `phpinfo()` still doesn't show the correct php.ini, you may need to set the `PHPIniDir` in your Apache configuration (if you are using Apache).

Comment: Reloaded the web server as suggested, phpinfo() now returns Loaded Configuration File C:\php\php.ini. However, having removed some of the semi colons for the extensions I wanted to load, Magento is still saying some of the extensions are missing, whilst a few whereby I deleted the semicolon it says is now present. Any ideas?

Comment: @RobWilliams In your php.ini, make sure your `extension_dir` is uncommented and pointed at "C:\php\ext" (then restart your web server again.)

Comment: @Don'tPanic Found two instances of extension_dir, as extension_dir = "./" and extension_dir = "ext". Having removed the ; from the extension_dir = "ext" (is that what you mean by pointing it at C:\php\ext?) I restarted it and am still getting the same result, extension still missing.

Comment: I mean explicitly set it to "C:\php\ext" instead pf "ext", (assuming that directory does exist as it would in the default PHP installation.) I am running PHP on windows and I had to make that change to get mine working.

Comment: I've changed it but it still is missing apparently. What do you mean by 'to get yours working'? What were you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Windows 10 with Bash shell, you can run

```
php -i | grep '\.ini'
```

That will show all configuration files loaded. People who work on Windows more often can likely identify the native way to do the equivalent operation natively.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when you're copying or renaming the php.ini file that it changes the file extension from .ini-developement (or .ini-production, depending on which one you use) to just .ini.  If you can't see the extensions on the files you can change that by clicking >view and selecting the **file name extensions** check box on the far right.

Alternatively, you can look at the file type column where it should say **configuration file** if the file extension has changed to .ini.