# cURL, Google App Engine and namespaces

Tags: php, google-app-engine, curl

I'm trying to port a PHP-based API over from shared hosting to Google App Engine. I've downloaded the PHP SDK, created a new application in the launcher, enabled cURL in php.ini (using `extension=curl.so`), and now I'm getting this error:

`Fatal error: Call to undefined function MyNamespace\curl_init() in C:\Users\David\Desktop\GAE\mysampleapp\classes\myclass.php on line 56`

If I add a backslash to curl_init() (to tell it not to use MyNamespace), I get this:

`Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in C:\Users\David\Desktop\GAE\mysampleapp\classes\myclass.php on line 56`

Short of enabling cURL_lite() (which I might tackle later, because that doesn't support the cURL options i need), how can i resolve this?

EDIT: My question differs from the suggested duplicate, because I'm following Google's own [instructions for enabling cURL](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/php_ini)

EDIT 2: I was able to get this running on the app engine SDK / launcher by changing the extension to php_curl.dll.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [curl\_init() function not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477535/curl-init-function-not-working)

Comment: @GiamPy This is different, because cURL is enabled in php.ini, using the [instructions on Google's own documentation site](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/php_ini)

Comment: Okay, so looks like cURL wasn't actually enabled. See my answer for clarification. Basically I had to remove the quotes on the GAE version, and change to php_curl.dll when doing it locally.

Answer (score 0):

So GiamPy's comment got me thinking, so I enabled phpinfo() in php.ini and found that cURL wasn't being loaded at all.

I changed the extension to php_curl.dll and it now works. A rookie mistake (I've been writing PHP apps for 10+ years), but this answer didn't fix cURL on the actual App Engine, until I saw an answer in another question, stating that removing the quotes in the extension line worked for them.

So now my local php.ini is:

`extension="php_curl.dll"`

While my GAE php.ini is:

`extension=curl.so`

And now I can use both.

Comment: Great! It could only have been a stupid mistake, not a big deal after all!