# How to send email using SendGrid

Tags: php, azure, sendgrid

I have been trying to set up email for a web page using SendGrid's PHP API, and I'm having no luck. I have tried their code from the Azure website as well as various examples I found while trying to Google it, and every time it returns nothing as a response, and the email isn't set. Here is the code I'm talking about:

```
<?php
 $url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/';
 $user = 'USERNAME';
 $pass = 'PASSWORD'; 

 $params = array(
      'api_user' => $user,
      'api_key' => $pass,
      'to' => 'email@gmail.com',
      'subject' => 'testing from curl',
      'html' => 'testing body',
      'text' => 'testing body',
      'from' => 'anna@contoso.com',
   ); 

 $request = $url.'api/mail.send.json';

 // Generate curl request
 $session = curl_init($request);

 // Tell curl to use HTTP POST
 curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);

 // Tell curl that this is the body of the POST
 curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);

 // Tell curl not to return headers, but do return the response
 curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
 curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

 // obtain response
 $response = curl_exec($session);
 curl_close($session);

 // print everything out
 print_r($response);
 ?>
```

It is also worth noting that I've tried using sendgrid-php accompanied with the code supplied with it, and that causes the page to simply not load. I'm really stumped right now, and any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: When I run your code as-is (including the dummy user/pass), I get a response.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477535/curl-init-function-not-working

Comment: I checked using phpinfo(), and it says curl support is enabled.

Comment: Have you tried capturing errors from cURL? http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Azure doesn't generate a SSL peer certificate for Azure Web Apps. If you add the code in your test code `$error = curl_error($session);`, you will get the error `SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain`.

You can simply add the code `curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);` to bypass the verification.

Otherwise, you can follow [Verify Peer Certificate from PHP cURL for Azure Apps](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2015/06/12/verify-peer-certificate-from-php-curl-for-azure-apps/) to add a certificate on Azure Web Apps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I used the code you supplied to bypass the verification, and now I'm getting a response. It's now giving a response, and it says it's successful, but the email isn't arriving. Any idea why that could be?

Comment: Nevermind. I had a typo in the email I was using. It's working. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible your version of cURL doesn't support SSL out of the box.

You can test this by putting the following at the top of your code:

```
if (!curl_version()['features'] & CURL_VERSION_SSL) {
    echo "SSL is not supported with this cURL installation.";
}
```

If it's not supported out of the box you have to configure it manually like this:

```
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
// path to CA certificate
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_CAINFO, '/etc/openssl/cert.pem');
```