# Initial web service not run - PHP

Tags: php, web-services

I am learning about web service and I had a problem trying to consume a static data file **data.txt**

this is my index.php

```html
<?php 
 
 $curl = curl_init("http://localhost/web_service/base.txt");

 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

 $answer = curl_exec($curl);
 $info = curl_getinfo($curl);

 if ($info['http_code' == 200] ){
  
  $data = explode(",", $answer);

  foreach ($data as $fruit) {
   echo "-> ". $fruit ."<br>";
  }
  
 } else {

  echo "error" . curl_error($curl);
 }

?>
```

And my base.txt contains only

**Banana,
Apple,
watermelon**

this is the error:

> The localhost page is not working
>
> Localhost is unable to process this request at this time.
>
> HTTP ERROR 500

I do not understand this error, my apache server is started.

I hope can you help me :)

Comment: can you access "http://localhost/web_service/base.txt" in your browser?

Comment: Check your server error logs to find out why it's throwing a 500 error.

Comment: [:error] [pid 1962] [client ::1:51590] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in /var/www/html/web_service_oncti/index.php:3\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/web_service_oncti/index.php on line 3    ((  This throws me the log ))     ************  When I try to access localhost / web_service / base.txt it throws me  "The requested URL /web_service/base.txt was not found on this server."

Comment: You need to install php curl.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [curl\_init() function not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477535/curl-init-function-not-working)

Comment: It worked, I had no Curl installed, I forgot I was on another computer (How silly). I had given an error on line 10, where the IF conditional is located, it was because I had defined ($ info ['http_code' == 200]) and it was wrong. Many thanks!! How do I put the approval that this problem has been solved?