# POSTing variables to an external page and reading it

Tags: php, curl

Say we have page 1:

```
<?php
$text=$_POST['text'];
echo 'You wrote "' . $text . '".';
?>
```

and page 2, which takes the user input, POSTs it to Page1, and gets the page (`You wrote (input).`). I'm not really sure about how to do this: googling (or better, stackoverflowing) a while, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481955/how-to-send-redirect-page-pass-variables-as-post-variables-from-a-php-script) question, which explains how to POST a variable to another page, but not how to get the code of the page. So, how to do both?

**EDIT**: An example of the actual situation.
The user inputs the number `245`. I get *the number, pass it to [this **external** page](http://www.numberempire.com/numberfactorizer.php), get the page*, retrieve the result (`5*7*7`) and show it.
In *italics* you see the part I need.

Comment: You want user-input; would a regular HTML form suffice?

Comment: What on earth is your question?

Comment: Not exactly. I need to input the text on a page like http://www.numberempire.com/numberfactorizer.php and retrieve only the result, and this is meant to be done on my PHP page. (API, Y U no exist.)

Comment: I see, but I don't know how to do it, as I never used cURL before. Please post an answer.

Comment: Nevermind, googled a bit further and found the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working example with cURL:

```
$function="sin(x)";
$var="x";
$url='http://www.numberempire.com/integralcalculator.php';
echo '<base href="' . $url . '">'; // Fixes broken relative links
$Curl_Session = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt ($Curl_Session, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($Curl_Session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "function=$function&var=$var");
curl_setopt ($Curl_Session, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
$content=curl_exec($Curl_Session);
curl_close ($Curl_Session);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to POST the data, and then you'll probably need to [parse the returned HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php).

Here's a blog post about [how to use cURL to post](http://davidwalsh.name/curl-post).  I'll leave using google to find an example of parsing HTML with PHP as an exercise for the reader . . .

Comment: Would you mind posting the proper code to POST the data and read the returned HTML (not parsed)?

Comment: [whathaveyoutried.com](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?  If you run into specific issues, feel free to ask more questions, but SO is not the site to come to and expect complete code written for you.

Answer (score 0):

page 1:

```
<form method="post" action="page2">
<input name="input" type="text"/>
<input type="submit" value="sendtopage2"/>
</form>
```

page 2:

```
<?php
$text=$_POST['input'];
echo 'You wrote "' . $text . '".';
?>
```

Comment: You missed the point. I don't want the user to go on page2: the process happens entirely on my server, which sends a request to page2 and retrieves and parses the result.